# Simple C# Question: Nesting Classes, Accessibility

Tags: c#, class, nested

I know this is probably simple, but I can't seem to figure out if it's possible to do this.

I have the following code:

```
public class A {    
thisMethod();  

 public class B {    
  someMethod();    
   }   
}


public class C {    
A myA = new A();    
A.B.someMethod();    
}
```

Why can't I access B if I've already instantiated A?

THanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an instance of A.B to call an instance method on A.B:

```
A.B foo = new A.B();
foo.SomeMethod();
```

In your example you weren't even trying to use the new instance you'd created.

If you come from a Java background, it may be worth pointing out that nested classes in C# are like *static* nested classes in Java. There's no implicit reference from an instance of the nested class to an instance of the container class. (The access is also the other way round - in Java an outer class has access to its nested class's private members; in C# the nested class has access to its outer class's private members.)

Comment: I guess the reason why I did it that way was just for logical grouping. So I'd have Player.Controls and Player.Library instead of all the methods in a huge class.

Comment: But why nest them? Why not have completely separate classes to start with, just in a "Player" namespace?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access it like it was a static method or a property of class A called "B".  You still need to create an instance of it - it is a class declaration. I think you're looking for :

```
public class A {    

public A()
{
   myB = new B();
}

thisMethod();  
public B myB
{
 get; set;
}

 public class B {    
  someMethod();    
   }   
}


public class C {    
A myA = new A();    
A.myB.someMethod();    
}
```

Just to note though, it's not recommended to expose nested classes publicly.